# Python3 mlpy installation error - ‘Py_InitModule3’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: linux, python-3.x, machine-learning

I was installing package mlpy on my Ubuntu 18.04 Machine using pip:

All the requirements were installed yet getting below compilation error. I also tried downloading the package directly and installing through it, the error I was getting is the same.

mlpy package version : 0.1.0 and python version is 3.6

Below is the command:

```
pip3 install mlpy
```

I tried installing using setup.py in mlpy package

```
pyhton3 setup.py install
```

Below is the processing message:

```
Collecting mlpy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/3c/be8ccff2aa3e5ce3b922cff026aadc62d3a671168e42616b1e0b8eccba12/mlpy-0.1.0.tar.gz (4.4MB)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlpy)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlpy)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlpy)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from mlpy)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from mlpy)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib->mlpy)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib->mlpy)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib->mlpy)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib->mlpy)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from matplotlib->mlpy)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib->mlpy)
Installing collected packages: mlpy
  Running setup.py install for mlpy: started
    Running setup.py install for mlpy: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l2ob_og8/mlpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-anrvg2fg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy
    copying mlpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy
    running egg_info
    writing mlpy.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to mlpy.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to mlpy.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to mlpy.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'mlpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.sdf' found under directory 'mlpy/libs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.sln' found under directory 'mlpy/libs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.suo' found under directory 'mlpy/libs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.exp' found under directory 'mlpy/libs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.ilk' found under directory 'mlpy/libs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found under directory 'mlpy/libs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*pdb' found under directory 'mlpy/libs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'mlpy/libs/hmmc/hmmc'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/generated'
    writing manifest file 'mlpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/agents
    copying mlpy/agents/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/agents
    copying mlpy/agents/fsm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/agents
    copying mlpy/agents/modules.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/agents
    copying mlpy/agents/world.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/agents
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/auxiliary
    copying mlpy/auxiliary/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/auxiliary
    copying mlpy/auxiliary/array.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/auxiliary
    copying mlpy/auxiliary/datasets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/auxiliary
    copying mlpy/auxiliary/datastructs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/auxiliary
    copying mlpy/auxiliary/io.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/auxiliary
    copying mlpy/auxiliary/misc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/auxiliary
    copying mlpy/auxiliary/plotting.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/auxiliary
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/cluster
    copying mlpy/cluster/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/cluster
    copying mlpy/cluster/vq.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/cluster
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/constants
    copying mlpy/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/constants
    copying mlpy/constants/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/constants
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/environments
    copying mlpy/environments/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/environments
    copying mlpy/environments/gridworld.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/environments
    copying mlpy/environments/nao.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/environments
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/environments/webots
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/environments/webots/controllers
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/environments/webots/controllers/serverc
    copying mlpy/environments/webots/controllers/serverc/serverc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/environments/webots/controllers/serverc
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/experiments
    copying mlpy/experiments/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/experiments
    copying mlpy/experiments/task.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/experiments
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/knowledgerep
    copying mlpy/knowledgerep/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/knowledgerep
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr
    copying mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr
    copying mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr/engine.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr
    copying mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr
    copying mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr/methods.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr
    copying mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr/similarity.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/knowledgerep/cbr
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/learners
    copying mlpy/learners/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/learners
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/learners/offline
    copying mlpy/learners/offline/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/learners/offline
    copying mlpy/learners/offline/irl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/learners/offline
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/learners/online
    copying mlpy/learners/online/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/learners/online
    copying mlpy/learners/online/rl.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/learners/online
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs
    copying mlpy/libs/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier.pyd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs
    copying mlpy/libs/hmmc.pyd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs
    copying mlpy/libs/noconflict.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/array_helper.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/array_helper.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/c45tree.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/c45tree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/coord.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/coord.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/random.cc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    copying mlpy/libs/classifier/random.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/hmmc
    copying mlpy/libs/hmmc/hmm.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/hmmc
    copying mlpy/libs/hmmc/hmm.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/hmmc
    copying mlpy/libs/hmmc/hmmc_module.c -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/hmmc
    copying mlpy/libs/hmmc/hmmc_module.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/hmmc
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/mdp
    copying mlpy/mdp/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/mdp
    copying mlpy/mdp/discrete.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/mdp
    copying mlpy/mdp/distrib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/mdp
    copying mlpy/mdp/stateaction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/mdp
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/mdp/continuous
    copying mlpy/mdp/continuous/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/mdp/continuous
    copying mlpy/mdp/continuous/casml.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/mdp/continuous
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/modules
    copying mlpy/modules/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/modules
    copying mlpy/modules/patterns.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/modules
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/optimize
    copying mlpy/optimize/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/optimize
    copying mlpy/optimize/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/optimize
    copying mlpy/optimize/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/optimize
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/planners
    copying mlpy/planners/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/planners
    copying mlpy/planners/discrete.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/planners
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/planners/explorers
    copying mlpy/planners/explorers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/planners/explorers
    copying mlpy/planners/explorers/discrete.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/planners/explorers
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/search
    copying mlpy/search/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/search
    copying mlpy/search/informed.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/search
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats
    copying mlpy/stats/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats
    copying mlpy/stats/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats
    copying mlpy/stats/_discrete.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats
    copying mlpy/stats/_multivariate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats
    copying mlpy/stats/_stats.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats/dbn
    copying mlpy/stats/dbn/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats/dbn
    copying mlpy/stats/dbn/hmm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats/dbn
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats/models
    copying mlpy/stats/models/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats/models
    copying mlpy/stats/models/_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats/models
    copying mlpy/stats/models/mixture.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/stats/models
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/tools
    copying mlpy/tools/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/tools
    copying mlpy/tools/configuration.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/tools
    copying mlpy/tools/log.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/tools
    copying mlpy/tools/misc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/tools
    running build_ext
    building 'classifier' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.6-EKG1lX/python3.6-3.6.5=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc: In function ‘PyObject* initclassifier()’:
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc:33:7: error: ‘Py_InitModule3’ was not declared in this scope
       m = Py_InitModule3("classifier", ClassifierMethods, "Classification module");
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc:33:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘Py_Initialize’
       m = Py_InitModule3("classifier", ClassifierMethods, "Classification module");
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           Py_Initialize
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc:34:18: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
       if (m == NULL) return;
                      ^~~~~~
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc:37:4: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
        return;
        ^~~~~~
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc:42:4: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
        return;
        ^~~~~~
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc:48:4: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
        return;
        ^~~~~~
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc:53:4: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
        return;
        ^~~~~~
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc:58:4: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
        return;
        ^~~~~~
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc:63:4: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
        return;
        ^~~~~~
    mlpy/libs/classifier/classifier_module.cc:68:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
      }
      ^
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------

Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-l2ob_og8/mlpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-anrvg2fg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-l2ob_og8/mlpy/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

`mlpy-3.5.0` https://sourceforge.net/projects/mlpy/files/ → Release date = 2012-03-12 → Older gcc, g++ to be used.

```
sudo apt install g++ g++-5 libgsl-dev
tar xvf mlpy-3.5.0.tar.gz 
cd mlpy-3.5.0/

export CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 && python3 setup.py build && sudo python3 setup.py install
```

No errors.

Answer (score 0):

(i cannot comment) 
the mlpy-3.5.0 compiles ok with gcc-7/g++-7, and note that on python 3.7, you'll need also a hack in /usr/include/python3.7m/pystate.h :

```
    #define exc_type       exc_state.exc_type
    #define exc_value      exc_state.exc_value
    #define exc_traceback  exc_state.exc_traceback
```

as those fields have moved.

have fun

Comment: Hi Please refer this page [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)